# Close found file but not emacs?

Tags: evil, find-file

I'm using emacs in terminal mode. I open it up and then use c-x c-f to edit a file.

I'm using evil mode so I then use `:x` to save and exit. I end up leaving emacs all together. Is there something else I can do here so that I just close the file?

Comment: In vi `:x` writes the file and exits the editor, so I would say that's 100% expected behaviour for the same command in emacs when using `evil`.

Comment: @phils not saying it's not the correct behavior. It's just that in emacs I more often want to close a buffer and keep emacs open so I can run additional commands.

Comment: A very quick google indicates that `:bd` is how one does this in vim, so.... the same, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about evil, but the usual emacs function is `kill-buffer`, and it's normally bound to `C-x k`. `C-h f kill-buffer` will show you what key (or keys) it's bound to.